# What is the BCa's Confidence interval in confint?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, bootstrap

I can not find any documentation on the type="bca" for the R command confint used to find confidence intervals. I am using this function to find the confidence interval of a bootstrap model. I know there are normal CI, percentile, and pivotal. Does the bca correspond to pivotal or something else?

Answer (score 3):

From `?boot::boot.ci`:

> bca: The intervals calculated using the adjusted bootstrap percentile (BCa) method.

See references therein, particularly Davison and Hinkley.

The code that actually does this is in the (hidden) function `boot:::bca.ci`.  The comments in the source code ([here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/boot_1.3-18.tar.gz) say:

```
#
#  Adjusted Percentile (BCa) Confidence interval method.  This method
#  uses quantities calculated from the empirical influence values to
#  improve on the precentile interval.  Usually the required order
#  statistics for this method will not be integers and so norm.inter
#  is used to find them.
#
```

Answer (score 2):

BCa is the bias-corrected with acceleration constant method for confidence interval estimation. See my book [Bootstrap Methods: A Guide for Practitioners and Researchers, 2nd Edition](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Bootstrap+Methods%3A+A+Guide+for+Practitioners+and+Researchers%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9780471756217), Chernick, 2007, or any other major text on bootstrap such as [An Introduction to the Bootstrap](https://doi.org/10.1201/9780429246593), by Efron and Tibshirani, 1994.